# Need help in understanding Reg Ex in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

Response text from sampler is :

```
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="PID_1498281212971253461">
```

The basic reg ex extractor mentioned for most of the correlations is (.+?). I have read the basics of the reg ex by googling and trying to understand reg ex better Base on the understanding, I tried Reg Ex (2nd Reg Ex) which I am not getting any matches.

Extractor1: [RegEx1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49C7f.jpg)
Extractor2:[RegEx2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLCKM.jpg)

Pls. help me in understanding. Appreciate your help.
This is my first post in any channel, pls ignore any comm errors.

Comment: You may just use `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` or try `\w+`. However, there are better ways to parse HTML in JMeter.

Comment: It worked Wiktor.. thank you very much for the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, your regular expression is basically missing a repetition meta character to wit `+`. In its current state it will match only something like `<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="PD_1">`

So you need to add `+` sign to the end of each character classes groups and your regular expression should start working as expected

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expresions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

---

[When it comes to parsing HTML responses using regular expressions is not the best option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), you might want to consider using [CSS/JQUery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead

[image: JMeter CSS/JQuery Demo]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and suggestion. I will work on the CSS/JQuery Extractor going forward :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XPath Extractor instead, will be simpler, here is the XPath to use

```
//*[@name='pid']/@value
```

Please make sure, you check the options, Use Tidy and Quiet in the XPath Extractor